# Casting to base class validity

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism

Say I have a class named `Base` and a class that derives from it called `SuperBase`. Given that `add` takes in a `Base*`, would either of these be valid:

```
SuperBase *super = new SuperBase;
bases.add(super);
```

Or

```
SuperBase *super = new SuperBase;
bases.add((Base*)super);
```

Comment: I can't think of a good title for the question, but I think this is better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first works as long as `SuperBase` publicly derives from `Base`, via an implicit conversion from derived-to-base:

```
struct base { virtual ~base() {} };
struct derived : base {};

base* b = new derived; // okay
```

The second works as well, but ignores the protection of `Base`:

```
struct derived : private base {}; // private base

base* b = new derived; // not okay, base is private
base* b = (base*)(new derived); // okay, but gross
```

If it's `private`, you probably shouldn't cast to it.

Comment: use `static_cast<Base*>` instead of a C-style cast `(Base*)` to make sure you are not dealing with undefined behavior.

Comment: But that's not true! (At least in C++03). C-style cast to an inaccessible base *is* guaranteed to work correctly (i.e. as if the base were accessible). The resultant pointer is a valid pointer to the base-class sub-object of type `Base` and it can be safely used as such. I.e. C-style cast is not a `reinterpret_cast` in this case, but rather a `static_cast` that ignores protection. It is, of course, still a bad programming practice, since it ignores protection, but it "works". Why do you say the behavior is undefined?

Comment: @Andrey: Oooh, I'm just flat out wrong then. I thought it acted exactly like `reinterpret_cast`. Fixed, thanks. @Milo: Forget I said that, it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid - a child can be used in a place where a reference/pointer to parent is expected. This is called polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Both would be valid, though type-casting `super` to `Base*` is not necessary.